Are causally isomorphic spacetimes Wick-related?
Take the time-orientable spacetimes $(M_1,g_1)$ and $(M_2,g_2)$ that are locally(to be clarified below) Wick-related and both are globally Wick-rotatable(to be clarified below) to the  same Riemannian manifold $(M,h_R)$ which according to Hervik, $(M_1,g_1)$ and $(M_2,g_2)$ are both locally everywhere (so globally) Purely Electric.
The Lorentzian metrics $g_1$ and $g_2$ induce binary relations $\ll_1$ and $\ll_2$ over their manifolds respectively which is defined as such:

$p \ll q \leftrightarrow$ there exists a time-like path connecting $p$ to $q$

Suppose there exists a bijection $\phi$ between $(M_1, \ll_1)$ and $(M_2,\ll_2)$. $\phi$ is a $\ll$-isomorphism if and only if:
$$p,q \in M_1 : p \ll_1 q \leftrightarrow \phi(p) \ll_2 \phi(q) $$
Spacetime $(M,g)$ is called globally Wick-rotatable iff it is every where locally Wick-rotatable.
Spacetimes $(M_1,g_1)$ and $(M_2,g_2)$ are said to be locally Wick-related if they can locally Wick rotated to the same Riemannian manifold $(M,h_R)$.
Take into account that Surya has shown that $\ll$-isomorphic past/future distinguishing spacetimes have the same topological dimension even though they might not be homeomorphic.
The question is:
Suppose the aforementioned spacetimes $(M_1,g_1)$ and $(M_2,g_2)$ are future AND past distinguishing, $\ll$-isomorphic and as mentioned before locally wick-related. Are these spacetimes globally Wick-related? If not what is the obstruction to the Wick-rotation? What about only past OR future distinguishing spacetimes?
What is the weakest level of causality on the causal ladder that guarantees Wick-relatedness of two spacetimes?

Please write a comment in case of voting

+1 — as for wanting downvotes explained, this has been debated ad nauseam on meta here with the conclusion being a general consensus that users should feel no obligation to comment when up or downvoting. Requests that we make an exception to this norm for you will likely result in further negative responses; best practice seems to be just ignoring it and focusing on the mathematics.

No matter what any comment is welcome at the end. I don't want to own anything here, and in case anything is found interesting can be rubbed without citation. @AlecRhea
